# Creating a Simple Installer for OS X

Tags: xcode, macos

I am quite new to Apple development for MAC OS X. I have a simple project that i wish to distribute as a DMG. I am new to this so don't know where to go from here

1. The application core that does performs the main application
2. A installer plugin

How do i create a DMG file from the installer plugin. How do i tie up my main application into the installer plugin. I am new, so a few pointers will be very helpful.

Kind Regards

Comment: Distributing apps within DMG files is acceptable and Apple does this themselves, outside of the app store.  Users are happy to drag the application into `/Applications` or use the links provided in the DMG.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a DMG using Disk Utility (found in `/Applications/Utilities/`) the process is very simple. You can read a little bit about "[Distributing your Application](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/porting/conceptual/portingunix/distributing/distibuting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002855-TPXREF101)" in this Apple Developer Library document.

As shown here, creating it is pretty easy:
[image: Using Disk Utlity to create a DMG]

You will notice that when I created the DMG initially it's set to a "read/write" format. After you've added your application, read me's, disk icon's and any artwork you can then convert it to a "read-only" DMG file.

Personally, though, I've been a long time user of [DropDMG](http://c-command.com/dropdmg/) which makes the process much simpler (n.b. I have no affiliation with [C-Command](http://c-command.com/) other they licensing DropDMG).